# Laravel / Eloquent - can not execute raw query

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, pdo, eloquent

This is the function that is executing the query:

```
    public static function getNearbyCityReport(float $lon, float $lat, float $rangeInKm){
    $query = "
        SELECT
            name,
            population,
            round((ST_Distance(rpoint, 'POINT( ? ? )', True)/1000)::numeric, 1) as distance,
            round(degrees(ST_Azimuth(rpoint, 'POINT( ? ? )'))::numeric,1) AS azimuth
        FROM
            gis_cities
        WHERE
            ST_DWithin(rpoint, 'POINT( ? ? )', 1000*?, True)
            AND
            feature_code != 'PPLX'
        ORDER BY distance;        
    ";
    $query = preg_replace('#\n#', ' ', $query);
    $query = trim(preg_replace('#\s{2,}#', ' ', $query));
    $expression = DB::raw($query);
    $result = DB::select($expression, [$lon, $lat, $lon, $lat, $lon, $lat, $rangeInKm]);
    dd($result);
```

When running this function I get the following exception:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (SQL: SELECT name, population, round((ST_Distance(rpoint, 'POINT( 24.8 43.3648 )', True)/1000)::numeric, 1) as distance, round(degrees(ST_Azimuth(rpoint, 'POINT( 24.8 43.3648 )'))::numeric,1) AS azimuth FROM gis_cities WHERE ST_DWithin(rpoint, 'POINT( 24.8 43.3648 )', 1000*300, True) AND feature_code != 'PPLX' ORDER BY distance;)

**The weird thing is that nothing seems to be missing from the built query shown in the exception and if I run that query on my database it works properly**. How can I make this work?

**LATER EDIT:**

Apparently the problem actually lies at PDO level and is caused by the fact that I am trying to add some parameters inside a quoted string:

```
(ST_Distance(rpoint, 'POINT( ? ? )', True)/1000)
```

See the **'POINT( ? ? )'** parts. If I remove all the quotes from my query then it works but of course it is not a valid postgis query anymore. Anybody know how this query should be written so that PDO will accept it ?

Comment: Have you tried separating the points x and y with comma?
`POINT( ?, ? )`

Comment: Hi all. As I've said, If I paste this query into the database console, I get the results I am expecting with no error.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the first SELECT in the query string?

Comment: Nope. And the the query shown in the exception is missing the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge the two coordinates into a single binding:

```
(ST_Distance(rpoint, 'POINT( ? )', True)/1000)

$result = DB::select($expression, [$lon.' '.$lat, ...]);
```